# How to prevent body scrolling while modal is open

Tags: html, css

I'm using [W3schools modal script](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal) and I want to add the function that prevent the entire body to scroll while the model is open. I did some minor modifications to the original script acording to my needs, I added a height to the modal and an overflow-y scrollbar. How can I prevent the body scrollbar to work while the modal is active?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is change the body atributes.
When the modal is open, set the height to 100% and hidden the overflow. When the modal is closed change the atributes do initial values (auto).

You can made this using css class, so when modal is opened you set a class to body with this atributes then when the modal is closed you remove the class. Or you can made this using javascript, and set the style tributes of the body manually.

I made the last way for you.

```
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"; // ADD THIS LINE
    document.body.style.height = "100%"; // ADD THIS LINE
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
    document.body.style.overflow = "auto"; // ADD THIS LINE
    document.body.style.height = "auto"; // ADD THIS LINE
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    document.body.style.overflow = "auto"; // ADD THIS LINE
    document.body.style.height = "auto";  // ADD THIS LINE
  }
}
```

The lines with the "ADD THIS LINE" comment is the line you need to add in your code.

Of Course you can put the css styles in one class and add or remove the class with javascript or jquery.

Comment: i know this is an old answer, but yeah this works. The problem is that the page automatically goes to the top most because of the overflow hidden. Do you have a fix for that?

Comment: have you figured this out?

Answer (score 5):

When you open the modal, set `document.body.style.overflow` to `hidden`, and set it to `scroll` when the modal is closed.