# How to disable back screen scrolling when popup is displayed

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am using this popup modal from https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp, and it works pretty well, the issue is that when the popup appears, the back screen is still scrollable, which i can not figure out how to resolve

Comment: add overflow hidden on body once the popup is displayed, on popup hide you can remove overflow on body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the modal is open you can set some CSS class for your html and body elements. For example: `.modal-open`.

```
.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

More here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53932629/8890700

Comment: It works great, but i think this is not working on safari or iphones